# linq-to-sql inserting unique row that already exists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

If you insert a row that already exists with a unique column, what happens? Does it silently fail or does it update the record? If it updates the row that exists, is there a way to have it fail instead? Or am I stuck using select to check for the row first?

Comment: Live dangerous, give it a whirl and let us know what happens! ;)  Honestly, that's usually the best way to find out.  If it's a live db, then just insert a temporary dummy record somewhere and try inserting another one.  LinqPad is invaluable here.

Comment: It will fail and complain at run time - try it out?

Answer (score 2):

You will get an exception generated by the backend sql server.

Comment: It might just be sqlite but no exception is being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

//EDIT: I updated the code to fit what you're looking for. In SQL Server please ensure that your Table Primary Key Column is an identity column with both seed and increment set to 1.
When you try to submit your class DON'T ADD the primary key. It will use this automagically.

An exception will be thrown if you attempt to insert a row into a table with the same unique ID. Updates in Linq-To-Sql are tricky... See my code below. The first part will fail but will be caught inside the try-catch. The second part is how to do an update. You gotta pull it out based on the primary key, change the fields, then submit it. See this blog:
http://www.richardbushnell.net/2008/02/18/how-to-update-data-with-linq-to-sql/

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         DataClasses1DataContext ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                ctx.Table_1s.InsertOnSubmit(new Table_1
                {
                    Name = "John"
                });
                ctx.SubmitChanges(System.Data.Linq.ConflictMode.FailOnFirstConflict);
            }

            var list = from i in ctx.Table_1s
                       select i;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        //OUTPUT: "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John" 
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"
        //        "John"


    }
}
```

Comment: No exception is being thrown unless I try to insert it twice which then I get a duplicate key exception inside the tracker which I am not sure is related.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Primary Key in your table is an identity column with a seed value of 1 and an increment value of 1? If it is then you won't have to insert a value for the primary key it will auto increment.

Comment: The table has both a auto incrementing primary key and a unique text field. The auto incrementing column is incrementing correctly. It still does not throw an exception though when there is a duplicate unique.

Comment: Linq-To-Sql will ignore any value set for the primary key in code if its an identity primary key with auto-increment +1 and seed value of 1. Try my Table... With my code in the example above and then select all the rows, there will be no duplicate primary keys. Thus, no exceptions thrown:

Comment: USE [db_dtsos]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_1]    Script Date: 08/10/2011 09:33:53 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
 [PrimaryKey] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [PrimaryKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: The issue is not the primary key. It is a separate column that is set as unique.

Comment: CREATE TABLE 'Users' ('ID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  , 'Username' TEXT    UNIQUE, 'Password' TEXT    , 'Usergroup' TEXT    , 'IP' TEXT    )

Comment: That's your problem right there. The text field. Try nvarchar(max).

Comment: Tried nvarchar and same result. Also I am using dblinq2007 as a provider.

Comment: @High let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2328/discussion-between-djohnsonm-and-high)